# Can't find any station that plays a particular song on Pandora

Tags: pandora

I'm looking for a specific song through Pandora and can't find any stations that play it.

The song I'm looking for in this case is "Love in the Library" by Jimmy Buffett.

Why can't I find it on Pandora? Are only certain songs available?

Answer (score 4):

Pandora stations don't really accept requests. You can try using that song as a seed for a new station to check that it's indexed. If it is, try using similar songs by the same artist as a seed. If it isn't, you're SOL (as soandos suggested).

Answer (score 2):

While Pandora has many songs, they do not have all of them. That sounds like the case here.